# Regexp js, получить строку между тегов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста получить строку между тегов. Дело в том, что я не могу вставить теги полностью (с открывающими и закрывающими символами), получается ошибка что это не функция. Как я могу преодолеть это?

```js
function getText(str) {
  let results = [],
    re = /h1([^}]+)h1/g,
    text;
  while (text = re.exec(str)) {
    results.push(text[1]);
  }
  return results;
}
console.log(getText("<h1>eqweqeeqweqqwe </h1> "))
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - вот тут можете потренироваться

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getText(s) {
  var res = []
  
  s.replace(/<h1\b[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/h1\s*>).)*)/g, (m, t) => {
    res.push(t)
  })
  
  return res
}

console.log(getText(`
  <h1>eqweqeeqweqqwe </h1> 
  <h1 class="q">qwe</h1 ><h1>qqq</h1>
  <h11>nope</h11>
`))
```